# What function should return to dplyr::do() to skip the case

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm applying user defined function in do(), but for some cases I don't need to do a calculation (to catch log(<0)). What should my function return? NULL nor () doesn't help.

```
my_function<-function(data) {
    if(data$a<0) {
       return(NULL) #?????????
    } else {
       return(data.frame(ln=log(data$a)))
    }
}

table<-data.frame(a=seq(10,-10,by=-1),b=seq(0,20,by=1))

result<-table %>%
    group_by(b) %>%
    do(
        my_function(data=.)
    )
```

Comment: In this case, perhaps you don't need a `do`: table %>% filter(a >0) %>% mutate(ln=log(a)) work for you

Comment: In this case yes, but it's a small example, real code is more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_function<-function(data) {
  if(data$a<0) {
    return(data.frame(NULL)) 
  } else {
    return(data.frame(ln=log(data$a)))
  }
}
```

Comment: Or just `data.frame()`